# Displaying a single result out of three results

Tags: views, theming, 9

I have a view block that is set up to produce three product titles sorted from a taxonomy term (*flowers*). I have a view whose machine name is *latest_products*.

In a preprocess function I use the following code.

```php
$variables['views_twig_var'] = views_embed_view('latest_products','block_1');
```

In a template, I use `{{ views_twig_var }}`, which produces all three titles on the page.

If it's possible, how would I use it in the template file to only show the first result?

`{{ views_twig_var[0] }}` doesn't work.

I would then use the second result further down the page, with the final result even further down.

For now, I created it in three different blocks, with each block producing a single result, but for my curiosity and for future reference I am wondering if there is a faster way.

Comment: How about duplicating the views block and use the views pagination params to display one item in the first block and 2 items in the second with an offset of 1 ? You can then do something like:
```
$variables['views_twig_var1'] = views_embed_view('latest_products','block_1');
$variables['views_twig_var2'] = views_embed_view('latest_products','block_2');
```
and display `{{ views_twig_var1 }}` and `{{ views_twig_var2 }}` wherever you want

Comment: That's exactly what I have done for now but I was wondering if there is a simpler way via twig to breakdown each result in to seperate sections.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I don't think so, the most optimized way would be not to use views and prepare two variables from the same request in a hook page which can't be done with views... unless I am wrong xD

Answer (score 2):

you can do it without preprocess, by using the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module, it gives you the possibility to render your view in twig with display filters and so on like the following:

```
{{ drupal_view_result('latest_products', 'block_1') }}
```

The `drupal_view_result` give you the array of result so you can get the first result with:

```
{{ drupal_view_result('latest_products', 'block_1')[0] }}
```

of type **ResultRow** and then get the entity with:

```
{{ drupal_view_result('latest_products', 'block_1')[0]._entity }}
```

For more information see the module [Cheat sheet page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a really useful module and easy too.